# Angular spinner for window.location.href

Tags: angular, windows, location, spinner, href

I want to load spinner in my angular code while calling

window.location.href ="sample URLLLLL"

tried set time out, load spinner set div true/false. Please help me to resolve this issue.  Please help me to resolve this issue.